# Select rows by applying whatever condition(if or case)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of records suppose below:

```
Id  Name  status  date

1    xx     1      2016-06-27 14:05:17.447
2    yy     2      2016-06-27 14:05:17.447
3    zz     1      2016-06-27 14:05:17.447
4    aa     2      2016-06-27 14:05:17.447
5    bb     2      2016-06-27 14:05:17.447
```

I want to select all the rows from above but 
for the rows who have status=1, i want to apply a condition that

```
select if status=1 and date<=getdate
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what version are you actually working with?

Answer (score 1):

```
select
Id,
Name,
case when   status =1 and date<getdate() then 'I want to select this row' else I don't want to select this row end as statuss 
,date
from
yourtable
```

Update: as per your edit,you need to apply your conditions in where clause

```
select * from yourtable
where status=1 and date<getdate()
```

Comment: please check, I have updated your answer with what I need as a example

Comment: see now this will filter the table. It will only select those records which have status =1 and date < getdate. but my requirement is that all records should be fetched else that those who have status=1 but who have status=1 then date condition also satisfy

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of, unless status is nullable:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Status, Date
FROM TableName
WHERE status <> 1 
OR date <= getdate()
```

If it is nullable, you can do this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Status, Date
FROM TableName
WHERE ISNULL(status, 0) <> 1 
OR date <= getdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Status
    (
      Id INT
    , Name CHAR(2)
    , status INT
    , date DATETIME
    );

INSERT  INTO #Status
        ( Id, Name, status, date )
VALUES  ( 1  -- Id - int
          , 'xx'  -- Name - char(2)
          , 1  -- status - int
          , '2016-06-27 14:05:17.447'  -- date - datetime
          ),
        ( 2  -- Id - int
          , 'yy'  -- Name - char(2)
          , 2  -- status - int
          , '2016-06-27 14:05:17.447'  -- date - datetime
          ),
        ( 3  -- Id - int
          , 'zz'  -- Name - char(2)
          , 1  -- status - int
          , '2016-06-27 14:05:17.447'  -- date - datetime
          ),
        ( 4  -- Id - int
          , 'aa'  -- Name - char(2)
          , 2  -- status - int
          , '2016-06-27 14:05:17.447'  -- date - datetime
          ),
        ( 5  -- Id - int
          , 'bb'  -- Name - char(2)
          , 2 -- status - int
          , '2016-06-27 14:05:17.447'  -- date - datetime
          ),
        ( 6  -- Id - int
          , 'cc'  -- Name - char(2)
          , 1 -- status - int
          , '2016-07-27 14:05:17.447'  -- date - datetime
          );

SELECT  *
FROM    #Status;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     #Status
               WHERE    status <> 1
             ) ,
        cteStatus1
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     #Status
               WHERE    status = 1
                        AND date <= GETDATE()
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    UNION
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cteStatus1;
```